# On click of next button the new value to be updated in text box

Tags: vb.net

In the code below I want Button7 to be used as the next button. This button takes the query result and shows it into a textbox (description). Now since there are multiple descriptions for same query I want the button when clicked to show the next description in the datagridview.

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    Dim conn5 As MySqlConnection
    conn5 = New MySqlConnection
    conn5.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;userid=dec;password=xVdRs84825uhLZtb;database=dec"
    Dim sda5 As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbdataset5 As New DataTable
    Dim bsource5 As New BindingSource
    Try
        conn5.Open()
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand
        ' Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT comment FROM bh_status WHERE jobid = '" & jobid & "';"
        Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT item_code,description,unit,quantity,material_cost,labour_cost,total_material_cost,total_labour_cost FROM ht_33kv_list_qty where project_id = '" & prj_id & "';"
        command = New MySqlCommand(sqlquery, conn5)
        sda5.SelectCommand = command
        sda5.Fill(dbdataset5)
        bsource5.DataSource = dbdataset5
        DataGridView4.DataSource = bsource5
        sda5.Update(dbdataset5)
        conn5.Close()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To DataGridView4.RowCount - 1

            Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1(3, i)
            Description.Text = cell.Value


        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're asking for.  Are you saying that you have multiple records from a database displayed in a `DataGridView` and one of those records is also displayed in one or more `TextBox` controls and you want to be able to change which record is displayed in the `TextBoxes`?

Comment: Try using a counter, thus for the first click your counter will increase. Do not forget to reset your counter at the end of the routine.

Answer (score 0):

To show in the *Description* textbox the value of all cells in the 3rd column of the *DataGridView1*, one at a time by clicking on the *Button7*, you can do the following:

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    With Me.DataGridView1
        Dim NextRow = .CurrentRow.Index + 1
        If NextRow >= .Rows.Count Then
            NextRow = .Rows.Count - 1   ' If you need a cycle then using ─────> NextRow = 0
        End If
        .CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1(.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, NextRow)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellChanged
    With Me.DataGridView1
        If .CurrentCell IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.Description.Text = Me.DataGridView1(3, .CurrentCell.RowIndex).Value.ToString
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```